# System.Net doesn't contain PeerToPeer

Tags: c#, p2p

I found a guide online on how to make a P2P program. While following it, it needed to add System.Net.PeerToPeer, but when I tried to add it, nothing prompted to get it imported.

I started searching online. Naturally it would be in the System.Net, but it doesn't show when I include it in the file. I tried NuGet, but no luck.

What is happening?

Comment: What version of .NET? What package did you try adding?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26884

Comment: @mxmissile I'm using .NET 6.0 and I didn't add any package. I just searched it in the nugets and didn't find anything

Comment: @HansPassant I believe I'm using .NET framework and not core

Comment: .NET 6.0 == core.  Pick the right project template to get started, it should have ".NET Framework" in its name.